# When embedding .cshtml files, there are errors parsing the files (types cannot be found)

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I had moved a project over from VS 2015 to VS 2017, and while editing the assembly with the embedded views, I noticed things like "@addTagHelper" and "@using" were failing, and not highlighting properly. How can I edit my embedded views like my main web project?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out, if you are using Visual Studio 2017, you need to make sure these lines are in your project file for the assembly with the embedded views:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
    <PropertyGroup>
       ...etc...
      <PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>
    </PropertyGroup>
```

By default, the project is set to `sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk"`.  Once this is changed, and `PreserveCompilationContext` added, the views should compile and highlight properly in the editor. You may also need to right click on the project, edit the settings, and set `Output type:` to `Class Library` (it was `Console Application` by default for me).

Comment: There is no need to unload solution files in VS2017, you can edit them directly within VS 2017. Just right click the solution and choose to edit the csproj. Once saved, VS2017 will automatically reload it. It was added, since editing csproj became more common with ASP.NET Core / .NET Core / NETStandard projects, because all the project.json stuff was moved in csproj now

Comment: Ah, that's cool, thanks. I just started using it a couple days ago and I'm still discovering the differences. ;)